# Division borders not being respected

Tags: css, layout, css-float

As clear and concise as possible.  I have a divsion, "the box", with a fixed width of 1200px that I use to contain several other divisions.  One of this divisions is a links bar, "pink bar", with a width of 100% and a height of 25px;.  I am trying to add an unordered list, displayed inline and floated right, within this "pinkbar" division.  The list displays, floated right, but on the line below the division rather than being within the division.  There is more than enough room with the division and absolutely no reason for it to need a new line.  I've tried tinkering with the various parameters, setting the width of "pinkbar" to 1200px for instance, but nothing works.  Can someone please explain why these list elements are able to exist outside the division in which they are called?

```
#thebox{
   padding-top: 0px; 
   margin-top: 0px; 
   margin-left: auto; 
   margin-right: auto; 
   width: 1200px; 
   height: 250px;
}

#pinkbar{
   background-image: url(../visual/pinkMenuBar.jpg); 
   background-repeat: no-repeat; 
   padding-top: 3px; 
   padding-left: 30px;
   padding-right: 10px; 
   margin-top: 0px; 
   margin-left: 0px; 
   margin-right: 0px; 
   width: 100%; 
   height: 25px; 
}

ul.nav{ 
    list-style-type: none; 
}

ul.nav li{
   border-left-width: 2px;
   border-left-style: groove;
   border-left-color: grey;
   display: inline;
   float: right; 
}

<div id="pinkbar" class="cambria3black">Tel: 111 111 1111
   <ul class="nav">
        <li>Testimonials</li>
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Fees</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Again, the list elements are displayed inline, floated right, and have the border.  They are just not within the confines of the division.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5UKqp/ Here is your code. I'm confused as to what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should float the container (`ul`) too, because it is a block element, so it will attempt to fill the biggest width of space it can - thus falling into the next line.

```
ul.nav { 
    list-style-type: none; 
    float: right; /* floats to the right, so will fit on the same line */
    margin: 0; /* gets rid of the default list margins */
}
```

I created [a little jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TUvSJ/), with the narrowed down (and working) version of your code.

Comment: This certainly pointed me in the right direction.  While the code you posted does work on jsFiddle, it had no effect whatsoever when I edited my code in that manner.  However, when I added the margin: 0; to the ul.nav li{} it brought everything back up to the proper line.  I still can't get the right side padding on #pinkbar to work properly, but I've compensated by just shortening the width of the entire division.